# Crosslet Package not Working

Tags: r, rcharts, rworldmap, rmaps

https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps

I tried reproducing this example and the map isn't showing:

```
 library(rMaps)
crosslet(
  x = "country", 
  y = c("web_index", "universal_access", "impact_empowerment", "freedom_openness"),
  data = web_index
)
```

Do I not have a package that will allow this to happen. I have installed the following:

```
rCharts
rMaps
jsonlite
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No error comes up, there's just no map in the output. The widgets are there in the plot area but the map doesn't seem to show up. @jeremycg

Comment: the code provided is reproducible but I just don't get why no map comes up but in the link provided a map is there

Comment: That's a "known" issue with the rMaps package that hasn't been solved in quite some time. See for example issue 83 and 99 on the github page you referenced.

Comment: Ok didn't know that, I'll accept that as an answer then @ekstroem