# Can I use function-crosslet to plot states in America?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, crossfilter, rmaps

```
library(rMaps)
crosslet(
  x = "country", 
  y = c("web_index", "universal_access", "impact_empowerment", "freedom_openness"),
  data = web_index
)
```

For this code, x="country", I want to change x to states. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830566/crosslet-package-not-working

Comment: and how to specify locations more specific than states？